# Android screen orientation: forcing landscape?

Tags: android, xml, screen, orientation

When I switch to a certain activity, I want that activity to show up in landscape mode.

In my XML for that actvitiy:

```
android:screenOrientation="landscape"
```

most tutorials stated this is all that's needed, yet when that activity is switched to it doesn't automatically change orientation.

fixed:
the code needed to be in the manifest under the specific activity

Comment: I see you already found the answer. You might want to either remove your question or provide an answer.

Answer (score 1):

In your activity tag, instead of just:

```
android:screenOrientation="landscape"
```

I would set:

```
 android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
```

It takes care of a few more things for you.

Answer (score 0):

fixed: the code needed to be in the manifest under the specific activity

Comment: You should accept your own answer to the question or remove the question