# Android choose particular landscape orientation

Tags: android, screen, orientation

I want to be able to select WHICH direction on landscape mode to be rotated to. I have a particular situation where the device will be landscape, but it appears upside down to what I want. The accelerometer does not seem to be working. 
**Please note:** this is for a specific enterprise app that is not going on the Google play store.

My code so far (in the manifest, under the application tag):

```
    android:screenOrientation="landscape"
```

I have looked at the following posts:
[How can i rotate the particular view landscape or portrait programatically in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26293222/how-can-i-rotate-the-particular-view-landscape-or-portrait-programatically-in-an)
[Android screen orientation: forcing landscape?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21243189/android-screen-orientation-forcing-landscape)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your line should be in activity tag (each if you have few). Also you might use

> android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"

API 9, on older versions it will be "normal" landscape

Answer (score 1):

Following is code which i used to display your activity into landscape mode only

```
<activity android:screenOrientation="landscape" 
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" 
android:name="yourActivty"/>
```

Comment: Yes thank you - I already have this, as stated in my question